# what are different methods to save dates in sqlite?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am new to android, i wonder what is the best way to save dates in sqlite  database in android.can i store it as a string or is there any particular date data type ?

```
   String CREATE_VENDOR_TABLE = "create table VENDOR(vendor_uid   
    integer,  project_name text, website_name text, date string)";
```

Comment: See http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html for a general overview of the different methods that are possible. (I recommend the ISO 8601 form, with either explicit GMT or TZ - avoid "local" or "unspecified" timezones. Mixing TZ's within the same column is problematic for ordering, but at least the information will be persisted correctly and can be used to derive correct GMT time.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

there are multiple ways to save date in sqlite, you can do it from java or you can save it as a data type in sqlite. see this [link](http://tips.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-insert-datetime-value-in-sqlite-database/) for complete info.

Comment: thank you for the link, this is what exactly i wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Each value stored in an SQLite database (or manipulated by the database engine) has one of the following storage classes:

**NULL**. The value is a NULL value.

INTEGER. The value is a signed integer, stored in 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, or 8 bytes depending on the magnitude of the value.

**REAL.** The value is a floating point value, stored as an 8-byte IEEE floating point number.

**TEXT.** The value is a text string, stored using the database encoding (UTF-8, UTF-16BE or UTF-16LE).

**BLOB.** The value is a blob of data, stored exactly as it was input.

**Boolean Datatype**
SQLite does not have a separate Boolean storage class. Instead, Boolean values are stored as integers 0 (false) and 1 (true).

***make function like given below.***

```
public string formateDate(String strDate)
{
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormaor = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd"); //your desired formate

        Date date = dateFormaor.parse(strDate); 
        return dateFormaor.format(date);
}
```